# Limite de envío mediante ajax

Tags: ajax, post

Hace un tiempo he venido preguntándome lo siguiente, y he buscado pero no he hallado respuesta a esto.

La pregunta es la siguiente.

¿Cual es la capacidad limite para hacer envío de datos, tanto para un request como response mediante ajax con metodo post?

Ej:

```
   HTML        Ajax     Controlador
 (Dato1) ---> (Dato1) ---> (Dato1)   Request
 (Dato2) <--- (Dato2) <--- (Dato2)   Response
```

Cuanto es la capacidad máxima que ajax soporta para el envío de Dato1 y Dato2, mediante post.

Agradezco cualquier comentario, saludos!

Comment: La capacidad va a depender de la configuración del servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solicitud POST, tanto desde el punto de vista del cliente como del servidor, es **exactamente igual** que cualquier otro tipo de solicitud. **No** hay distinción entre GET, POST, PUT, o cualquier otra (excepto, tal vez, el *upload* de archivos, que se distingue por su `Content-type`).

Dejando de lado el cliente, **todos** los servidores tienen establecido un límite para el tamaño máximo de envío ante **cualquier** tipo de solicitud. Resumiendo: depende de la configuración del servidor.

Por ejemplo, según la [documentación de apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody), en este servidor se puede configurar un límite en 0 y 2GB.

Para el cliente, sencillamente, **no hay límite**. Se intenta mandar datos hasta que reciba algún tipo de error del servidor. Por ejemplo, en temas AJAX, lo que mandes **ya ha de estar en memoria**, por lo que no presenta problemas. Y, para *uploads*, el tamaño del archivo es conocido **antes** de iniciar la subida.

**EDITO**

No tenía pensado extenderme mucho en esta respuesta, pero en fín :-)

Técnicamente hablando, una solicitud (del tipo que sea, da igual) se limita a establecer un *socket* (si no hay ya uno) entre el cliente y el servidor.

Por dicho *socket*, la información que puede circular es **ilimitada** hasta que una de las partes (cliente o servior) lo *cierren*.

Ahora bien, HTTP establece un *protocolo* claro en que bytes han de circular, y en que orden, para que ambas partes *se entiendan*.

Una petición `POST` típica tiene este formato (no es exacto, pero para hacernos una idea):

> `POST URL_DEL_OBJETO_EN_CUESTIÓN`
>   `UNA_O_VARIAS_CABECERAS`
>   `CONTENT-BODY_SI_LO_HAY`

Vale. Como dije, no hay límites *teóricos*, pero **si hay límites prácticos**. Puesto que la información que circula **no es instántanea**, el servidor debe almacenarla en algún lugar **hasta que esté toda completa**, para poder decidir que hacer con ella.

Estas decisiones **no siempre requieren** de todos los datos: por ejemplo, un *proxy* intermedio tan solo necesita **la URL** para decidir que hacer. Para *retransmitir* el resto de los datos, puede usar un pequeño *buffer* interno, pero no necesita *almacenarlo todo*, puesto que no lo va a usar y, simplemente, lo va a *retransmitir* hasta su destino final.

Este es el motivo del **porqué** unos datos tienen limites distintos a otros. Si la URL solicitada es muy larga, un posible *proxy* intermedio **no podría procesar la socilitud**, puesto que **si necesita** ese dato concreto para tomar una u otra decisión. Pensemos en aparatos pequeños, de reducida capacidad de proceso, y poca memoria disponible.

Ahora, pensemos en el servior. Dependiendo del tipo de datos (obtenido del `Content-Type`, incluido en las cabeceras), puede ser necesario **obtenerlo completo** antes de poder procesarlo.

Por desgracia para nuestro *querido* servidor, los datos a enviar pueden ser bastante grandes. Como dijimos antes, hay que esperar a tenerlos todos antes de procesarlos. ¿ Como lo hacemos ? pues usando un bloque de memoria, en el que almacenaremos todos los datos, según los vamos recibiendo.

¿ Y no podemos hacerlo de otra forma ? Por ejemplo, usando un buffer en disco, ...

**Claro** que podemos. Pero... pensemos en el **rendimiento**. Si por cada petición hay que escribir en disco un número indeterminado de *bytes*, y luego realizar varias lecturas *extra* para procesarlo, ... eso con cada petición de cada cliente ... el rendimiento del equipo apenas daria para 10 o 20 conexiones simultáneas. Un día tranquilo.

Comment: Gracias por responder :D sin embargo, get tiene el problema de máximo cantidad de caracteres por la url, por lo cual dudo que tenga una máxima de 2gb si esto esta comprometido por otro aspecto que es lo máximo de caracteres que aguanta la url

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Lo del límite para el GET ya se pregunto. Hay una recomendación del límite para la URL, creo que de 1024. Pero la **conexión** en si puede seguir mandando datos sin problemas. Tanto la URL como las cabeceras y el contenido van en la misma conexión.

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda **No** te confundas. Tu preguntas por el límite del tamaño del envío. El envío tiene 3 partes **bien** diferenciadas, que no interfieren una con las otra: URL, cabeceras, y cuerpo. La suma de las 3 es *indefinida* e *ilimitada*. Otra cosa es que **una** de ellas tenga un límite *recomendado*, pero eso no afecta a las demas.

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda editada la respuesta.

Comment: bien completa la respuesta. Agradezco tu disposición a compartir el conocimiento :D